# Brackets use in where clause

Tags: sql

Case1:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE Price NOT BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Case2:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE (Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
AND NOT CategoryID IN (1,2,3)
```

Why is case 2 brackets are used after `Where`, what is the reason behind this and it's logic?

Comment: They are not needed, but some people find it easier to write and read. (I don't...)

Comment: it just make the query easier to read... that all

Comment: Or harder to read...

Comment: They are unnecessary here, but good practice when dealing with `OR` rather than `AND` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The importance of the brackets is given in the example below.
They are used in `SQL` when combining the `AND` and `OR` operators in the where clause to describe the precedence between these two operators.

Example where brackets are needed:

```
select 
    PK_Branch,
    [Branch Name DE],
    Country 
from 
    DimBranch
where 
    ([Branch Name DE] like 'Lyss (CH)' or [Branch Name DE] like 'Sevilla') and Country like 'Spain'
```

Results with brackets:

[image: Brackets]

Results without brackets:

[image: Wo Brackets]

Comment: No, even in your query the parentheses are not needed, because `AND` has precedence over `OR`. However, when combining `AND` and `OR` one should always use parentheses in my opinion. In your query they may not be needed, but they enhance readability a lot and should hence be used anyway.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you were right. I have updated the answer!

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian Could you please provide at least an example of your own? Yours is 'cut' from [an external source](techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php). Can be easily find by googling. It should not be hard to provide an example of your own considering the situation. This is to encourage original answers and not permanent copy pasting just for reputation gaining purposes. Thanks

Comment: @NullException Sure! the example that you requested was provided... Directly from my database

Answer (score 1):

The importance of the brackets is given in the example below.
They are used in `SQL` when combining the `AND` and `OR` operators in the where clause to describe the precedence between these two operators.

Example where brackets are needed:

```
select 
    PK_Branch,
    [Branch Name DE],
    Country 
from 
    DimBranch
where 
    ([Branch Name DE] like 'Lyss (CH)' or [Branch Name DE] like 'Sevilla') 
    and Country like 'Spain'
```

Results with brackets:

[image: Brackets]

Results without brackets:

[image: Wo Brackets]